# Different Scopes in Google Analytics Service Account

Tags: java, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

Directly from [Google Developers Api for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2)

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("[[INSERT SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL HERE]]")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
            // .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
            .build();
        // set up global Plus instance
        plus = Plus.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
            .setApplicationName("Google-PlusServiceAccountSample/1.0")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

Now I wanted to know what are the different

> ServiceAccountScopes

that we can use ??

Here, its using **PlusScopes.PLUS_ME**, some where it uses **AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY** .

I really don't have any idea about these scopes.

Further, when i try to use *AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY* in my analytics-cmline-sample project from [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/analytics-cmdline-sample/instructions.html)

It doesn't allow me to. Saying its accepting a List while I am providing a String.
Does anyone has any idea whats this **ServiceAccountScopes** is all about ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question is that you should put the scope in a arraylist, like this:

GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY));